# How to fix the NameError: name 'names' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program for my programming class where I make  an automated email to send to  multiple people's emails. However it is saying that names is not defined  and I cannot figure out  what I am doing wrong,  could someone help please. The Code is pasted below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def get_contacts(emails):
    names = []
    emails = []
    MY_ADDRESS = noreply@deals.com
    with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
        for a_contact in contacts_file:
            names.append(a_contact.split()[0])
            emails.append(a_contact.split()[1])
    return names, emails

from string import Template

def read_template(email_template):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
        template_file_content = template_file.read()
    return Template(template_file_content)

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# For each contact, send the email:
for nameS, emailS in zip(names, emails):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()       # create a message

    # add in the actual person name to the message template
    message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title())

    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['From']=MY_ADDRESS
    msg['To']=email
    msg['Subject']="This is TEST"

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    # send the message via the server set up earlier.
    s.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: You need to call `get_contacts()` and assign the result to the variables.

Comment: You never call `get_contacts` anywhere, and there is no `names` (neither `emails`) in the same scope as your `for`. (They are variables with these names inside of `get_contacts`, but that's not in the same scope.)